# <h1><%= contrycode('93') %></h1>

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, ejs

I want to write a helper function.

**node.js page**

```js
app.locals.contrycode = async(name) => {
  const id = name
  var idi

  await CountryData.find({ phoneCode: id })
                    .then(contryname => {
                      idi = contryname[0].name
                      console.log(contryname[0].name)
                      console.log(contryname)
                      console.log("............")
                    }).catch(err => {
                      console.log(err)
                    })


  const name1 = idi
  console.log('test------ ', name1)
  return name1;
}
```

**ejs page**

```
<h1><%= contrycode('93') %></h1>
```

and I'm getting output => `[object Promise]`

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/179)?

Comment: any update on this same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
// USING PROMISIFIED FUNCTION
app.locals.contrycode = async(name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        CountryData.find({ phoneCode: id })
        .then(contryname => {
            idi = contryname[0].name
            resolve(idi) ;
            console.log("............")
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    })
}
```

or

```
// USING ASYNC/AWAIT
    app.locals.contrycode = async(name) => {
      const id = name
      var idi= 

      let contryname = await CountryData.find({ phoneCode: id })
      return contryname[0].name;
    }
```

Comment: Hello I have tried it,It will response with [object Promise]

Comment: no.... i am wrtiting this code on .js file   and i am calling this function from ejs page by <h1><%= contrycode('93') %></h1>

Comment: If that you will be needing to replace the value using javascript only.